# How to port Libgdx to html5

Tags: html, libgdx

I've found the only article in Google
[here](http://moldedbits.com/blog/2012/03/13/porting-libgdx-applications-to-html5/).
But I don't understand it.

"Import the libgdx projects(checked out from svn) into your workspace in eclipse."

Hmm. There are no no detailed instruction how to do it. 
And I'd like to port my own project, not someone's from svn.
I don't understand how to port superjumper example from svn anyway.

"Open project properties -> java build path in Eclipse. 
In the projects tab, add gdx, gdx-backends-gwt and your libgdx project."

But the project tab is empty there. And "add" is turned off.

BTW, are Libgdx games on html5 extremely slow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/gdx-setup-ui.jar

download it and fill your project details...
It will create android, html and desktop project to your specified directory.

Import that to your eclipse and you are good to go.

Comment: I can create Libgdx projects. I've copied existing desktop project to Eclipse workspace folder. But java build path-projects window is empty anyway